# Are there ever non-universal cones to the identity functor?

Tags: ct.category-theory

An initial object in e in C is also a universal cone to the identity functor, but can there ever be a category where an object k in C exists with a cone to the identity functor, but k is not initial. It would seem that in all examples I can think of, a cone to the identity functor must equalize all maps in the category, and so can only come from an initial object.

Comment: Consider what happens in the opposite of the category of sets

Comment: Saying "must equalize all maps in the category" is imprecise. What actually happens is that in such cone $(\varkappa_x:k\to x)_{x\in\operatorname{Obj}(C)}$ every $\varkappa_x$ must equalize all parallel pairs with domain $x$; it does neither imply that there are no other morphisms from $k$ to $x$, nor that all other morphisms $k\to x$ should also equalize all parallel pairs with domain $x$.

Comment: I said it seems that way in all examples I could think of, but yeah the language is imprecise. But that is what I'm curious about i.e. can such cones arise without using an initial object (or zero object etc.)? Thanks, I see now we can just remove the zero objects, but can a cone example arise naturally without having had a zero object initially? (see my comment below). What I meant about equalising all maps was referring to the cases when the zero object is actually involved, though thanks for clarifying the definition of the cone...

Comment: As Tim Campion's answer shows, the initial object is in a sense inescapable: it should be present in the idempotent completion, and the cone will  factor through it there.

Comment: Regarding categories without terminal/initial/zero acquiring one in the idempotent completion - again, move backwards: remove, say, terminal in sets; the idempotent splitting of that will give you sets back, since in the remaining category any nonempty set $X$ will have an idempotent endomorphism $X\to 1\to X$ whose splitting will recover $1$

Comment: For a category with, for example, coconstant maps between any pair of objects, but with no zero object to factor through, I understand that the zero can be generated in the idempotent completion, but for the general definition of coconstant map to be worthwhile, you'd expect some natural examples of categories with such maps that don't have a zero for them to factor through. Otherwise coconstant maps always get defined with implicit use of a zero... Sorry for the clumsy expression of this...

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. You do have a definition independent of anything - a coconstant morphism is the one that equalizes any parallel pair emanating from its target. You cannot reduce this to factoring through initial in general - e. g. in any poset every morphism is coconstant (as well as constant).

Answer (score 3):

Not every cone for the identity functor comes from an initial object. For instance, if $C$ has a zero-object, then for any object $A$ there is an obvious structure of cone for the identity functor given by the family of zero morphisms with domain $A$.

In general, $A$ admitting a cone for the identity functor amounts to saying that there is a [coconstant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_morphism) morphism $A\to B$ for each $B$.

Comment: Ok, thank you, that shows there are cones to the identity functor from things other than an initial object (which answers my question). But can such cones exist in a category without an initial object? i.e. why isn't the existence of a cone to the identity functor a sufficient condition for the existence of an initial object (I assume it's not)? There must be an example of a cone to the identity functor in a category without an initial object.

Comment: @B.G.G. Just remove the zero object

Comment: The zero object is part of the definition of all the cones to the identity in the example, so it cannot be removed

Comment: @B.G.G. Sorry for misunderstanding. Take any full subcategory of a category with zero object $0$. Then for any object $A$ there is a cone to the identity functor, $0_{A,B}:A\to B$ for each $B$, where $0_{A,B}:A\to0\to B$ is the composite morphism which survives in the subcategory since this subcategory is full by definition.

Comment: A punctured category might be what you're looking for (it's essentially a category with a $0$ object from which you removed -or not- the zero object)

Answer (score 3):

Note that if $\gamma: id_C \Rightarrow const_t$ is a cocone, then the component $\gamma_t: t \to t$ is an idempotent. Splitting this idempotent yields a terminal object. By the universal property of the terminal object, cocones on the identity functor are then in bijection with pointed objects of $C$ (a pointed object of $C$ is an object $c \in C$ equipped with a map $1 \to c$). The bijection sends a pointed object $f: 1 \to c$ to $f \circ \gamma$ where $\gamma$ is the canonical cocone from the identity to the terminal object.

In general the idempotent $\gamma_t$ need not split, but one can still say the following. A cocone on $id_C$ exists if and only if the idempotent completion $\tilde C$ of $C$ has a terminal object, and cocones on $id_C$ are in bijection with pointed objects of $\tilde C$ whose underlying $\tilde C$-object lies in $C$.

Comment: Sorry, I answered your question in dual form. This saved me from talking about "co-pointed objects".

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate this, and maybe I'm misunderstanding your answer, but this doesn't seem to show there can be a case where a cone (or cocone) to the identity exists without an initial (or terminal) object. If idempotents don't split i.e. there's no terminal object, then can a cocone on the identity still exist? Or dually as in the original question, can a cone to identity still exist? You say it exists iff the idempotent completion has a terminal object, could you prove this, and can you think of an example where idempotents don't split, but a cone on identity exists?

Comment: @B.G.G. An example is in my comment to another answer: in a full subcategory of a category with zero object there are lots of idempotents $A\to0\to A$ which do not split unless the full subcategory contains the zero object. The cones from any object to the identity (as well as from the identity to any object) still exist whether the subcategory contains 0 or not.

Comment: Ok yes I see your point, those maps remain when the zero object is removed. For example for pointed sets, all the maps from an object A collapsing to the basepoint of any object B form a cone, but the zero object isn't needed for the definition... I would still be interested in the proof of the characterisation given by Campion above...

Comment: @B.G.G. Proof is, I believe, straightforward. One direction is proved in the answer: from a cone you get a terminal in the idempotent completion. For the other, if the idempotent completion of $C$ has a terminal, take the cone to it and restrict to $C$.

Comment: @B.G.G. As მამუკაჯიბლაძე says, the proof is straightforward as soon as you know that the idempotent completion $\tilde C$ of $C$ always exists, is unique, and the inclusion $C \to \tilde C$ is fully faithful. If you get stuck at some point trying to prove the result from these facts, let me know where you're stuck and we should be able to sort it out.

Comment: Thanks, this is all clear now. Still I'm wondering if there are any examples of categories that arise naturally without a terminal object, but whose idempotent completion has a terminal object. That is, an example that didn't just result from removing the terminal object. If not, it seems like definitions such as that of constant map are a bit artificial, and that cones to the identity and constant/coconstant/zero maps really only exist where there is an initial/terminal object (even if it has been removed).